# Play BBC Radio without Flash Player

Tags: flash, iplayer, bbc

Take this URL: http://www.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/console/b00vf4rp . It has a silly animated Flash Player which canes my CPU. I'm running with Mac OS X 10.6 on a MacBook Pro 13. I am also running the latest version of Flash: `10.1.85.3`.

Can I listen to BBC radio streams without using Flash?

Who's fault is this, I take it Windows users don't see high CPU usage?

Comment: The modern browsers include a development option. (For desktop developers to develop smartphone apps.) If you turn this on you can make your computer appear as a smartphone. You will then be delivered the HTML5 video.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The page below is the answer...  It contains links to Flash (spit) and non flash media sources for all(?) their radion stations. :-)

How can I listen to BBC Radio stations and programmes online? http://www.bbc.co.uk/faqs/online_radiohowto
<strike>http://faq.external.bbc.co.uk/questions/radio/online_radiohowto/?src=interstitial</strike>

And for regional stations: https://iplayerhelp.external.bbc.co.uk/help/playing_radio_progs/local_radio_streams

For instance radio 1: http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio/listen/live/r1.asx

Comment: They don't provide this service anymore afaik.

Answer (score 8):

I listen to Radio 1 using Windows Media Player with the active content disabled.

The URL I use is:

`http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio/listen/live/r1.asx`

If you want to listen to other BBC radio stations then change the number at the end of the URL e.g `r2.asx`. `r3.asx` etc

Much better than the web player on the BBC site. I found that if I listened for a couple of hours my flash would bomb out.

I presume you will be able to do something similar on your Mac?

Comment: This link is no longer working.

Comment: As of Dec 31 2014, the BBC [no longer provide Windows Media streams](http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/internet/entries/28dfd220-7ca1-3683-ac16-3938cfb4b882)

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be an option on the site to allow the listening to radio programmes with out a video component. The "in page" version is an animated speaker the "pop out" version has more animations.

On Windows if you right click over the Flash player you can get to an options dialog that has an "Enable hardware acceleration" option on the Display tab.

Is this available on the Mac version? If so, can you enable it.

As to who's fault it is - there are too many steps in the chain where things can go wrong to apportion blame to one individual or group.

Answer (score 2):

I think that any audio player that lets you add URL to playlist will play the audio stream for you. Thats the clean way, how I do it. I use classic old Winamp on Windows. Just put there URL like Barry has mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion from another forum was to use Adblock Plus addon for your browser. You then right click on the animation to get the option of blocking it. Works on my mac with firefox and cpu usage went from 70 to 25

Answer (score 1):

To watch iPlayer on a Mac without Flash make it appear that the computer is an iPad.

To do this with Safari web browser turn on the "Develop" menu.
Then select "User Agent>iPad".

The only disadvantage is that the picture is iPad, or smaller, size.

Answer (score -1):

Follow the link:
http://bbcstreams.com/
Remember to delete the word link in brackets at the end of each one.
I use VLC Media Player.